# Wechat access token conflict

Tags: access-token, wechat

I am able to successfully generated and use the access token. When I generate new access token, the old token is still valid and it starts giving authentication error after a while. 
Is there any timeframe defined for which the old access token will continue to be valid ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [WeChat wiki](http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Access_token) you should receive the expire time in your JSON response.

```
{"access_token":"ACCESS_TOKEN","expires_in":7200}
```